# How do I set up Compound Predicate Template in NSPredicateEditor

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I am using a PredicateEditor but am struggling to get compound predicates to work.

I have a predicate like the below:

[image: predicate UI]

I want to be able to nest the top predicate (i.e. “All of the following are true”) so that I can do searches like:  a is true AND b is true AND ( c is true OR d is true).

I set up the templates for the predicate in code (as I couldn’t get IB to work for this) as follows:

```
if let editor = predicateEditor{

    var stringExpressions: [NSExpression] = []
    var stringOperators: [NSNumber] = []
    for p in LTDEddingtonNumberProperty.StringProperties{
        stringExpressions.append(NSExpression(forKeyPath: p.rawValue))
    }
    stringOperators.append(NSNumber(value:NSComparisonPredicate.Operator.contains.rawValue))
    stringOperators.append(NSNumber(value:NSComparisonPredicate.Operator.equalTo.rawValue))
    stringOperators.append(NSNumber(value:NSComparisonPredicate.Operator.notEqualTo.rawValue))

    let stringTemplate = NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate.init(leftExpressions: stringExpressions, rightExpressionAttributeType: NSAttributeType.stringAttributeType, modifier: NSComparisonPredicate.Modifier.direct, operators: stringOperators, options: Int(NSComparisonPredicate.Options.caseInsensitive.rawValue))

    let booleanExpressions: [NSExpression] = [NSExpression(forKeyPath: LTDEddingtonNumberProperty.isWeekDay.rawValue)]
    var booleanOperators: [NSNumber] = []
    booleanOperators.append(NSNumber(value:NSComparisonPredicate.Operator.equalTo.rawValue))
    booleanOperators.append(NSNumber(value:NSComparisonPredicate.Operator.notEqualTo.rawValue))

    let booleanTemplate = NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate.init(leftExpressions: booleanExpressions, rightExpressionAttributeType: NSAttributeType.booleanAttributeType, modifier: NSComparisonPredicate.Modifier.direct, operators: booleanOperators, options: Int(NSComparisonPredicate.Options.caseInsensitive.rawValue))

    let compoundTemplate = NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate.init(compoundTypes: [NSNumber(value: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.and.rawValue), NSNumber(value: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.or.rawValue), NSNumber(value: NSCompoundPredicate.LogicalType.not.rawValue)])

    editor.rowTemplates.append(contentsOf: [stringTemplate, booleanTemplate, compoundTemplate])
}
```

I’m guessing there’s a problem with the setting up of the Compound Predicate template but have not been able to figure out what.

Any suggestions ?

I am using Swift 4 and Xcode 9

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I can’t add a second compound predicate. Ie the one at the top of the image.

Comment: Do you want to add a row in code? The user can add a compound row by holding down the Option key.

Comment: Thank you. That’s it. Pleased it’s not a coding problem.